# Are there any ways to increasing the gain and ICMRs to this opamp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, cmos

[image]

Here's the netlist of this CMOS opamp schematics.

```
M_M1 N16151 VIN N16182 N16182 MbreakN L=0.1u W=9.5u
M_M2 N16178 VIP N16182 N16182 MbreakN L=0.1u W=9.5u
M_M3 N16151 N16151 VDD VDD MbreakP L=0.1u W=5u
M_M4 N16178 N16151 VDD VDD MbreakP L=0.1u W=5u
M_M5 N16182 N16219 VSS VSS MbreakN L=.95u W=19u
M_M6 VO N16178 VDD VDD MbreakP L=1.3u W=76.1u
M_M7 VO N16219 VSS VSS MbreakN L=1.3u W=76.1u
M_M8 N16219 N16219 VSS VSS MbreakN L=.95u W=19u
R_R1 N16219 VDD 45k TC=0,0
```

And it's based on .38 TSMC CMOS
I have problem increasing the gain and IMCR.
Are there any ways to reach that without increasing lots of the area of it?

Comment: Lots of tradeoffs to make, without knowing your other performance specs and constraints it's hard to make recommendations.  What's "increasing lots"? Adding another amplification stage is one obvious possibility.

Comment: Why are V3 and V4 needed?